# Meteor , collectionFS with cordova plugin ( org.apache.cordova.media )

Tags: cordova, meteor, collectionfs

here is the case, I wanna make an "whatsapp" like function of recording voice clip and save it in meteor apps using collectionFS.

but it seems not support media object of cordova and show

```
[Log] Uncaught Error: Error: DataMan constructor received data that it doesn't support:2199:http://meteor.local/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51 (console-via-logger.js, line 173)
```

and here is the code related

```
'click .voice':function (argument) {

 if(!isRecording){
   console.log('startRec');
   media  = getNewRecordFile();
   media.startRecord();
   isRecording=true;

 }else{
   console.log('stopRec');
   media.stopRecord();
   playAudio(media.src);
   isRecording=false;

    Sounds.insert(media,function (err, fileObj) {
      if(err){
        alert(err);
      }else{
        alert('success');
      }
    });

 }}
```

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/issues/457

Comment: so is there a way to create the fileObj from a path directly? I also encountered similar issue and seems that a Media object created from cordova is not compatible with the fileObj that insert is using. Actually what is the type of fileObj? Hope someone can help.